# Reduce twitter bootstrap heading size by ratio

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Not sure if this is possible. I think the Twitter Bootstrap heading size is too big. `h1` is `36px`; `h2` is `30px`, and so on.

Is there any way to reduce the heading size by ratio? Say I just want 90% of each heading instead. I don't wanna declare each heading's font size one by one.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe bootstrap sets a baseFontSize variable and almost all font-size properties are relative to that, example: font-size: @baseFontSize * 2; You could change that to something smaller.

Answer (score 7):

I realise this thread is over 18 months old now, but in case someone comes across this again, the latest version of Bootstrap (v3.1.1) has all heading font sizes set in the `less/variables.less`, like so:

```
@font-size-h1: floor((@font-size-base * 2.6)); // ~36px
@font-size-h2: floor((@font-size-base * 2.15)); // ~30px
@font-size-h3: ceil((@font-size-base * 1.7)); // ~24px
@font-size-h4: ceil((@font-size-base * 1.25)); // ~18px
@font-size-h5: @font-size-base;
@font-size-h6: ceil((@font-size-base * 0.85)); // ~12px
```

So it's just a case of tweaking the multipliers for each of these to have an affect.

Comment: `Solution:` Replace the double brackets with single brackets. This is a bug in my view.

Comment: @B.Martin the code above is a snippet out of the bootstrap less/variables.less file not code I've written. The code is still the same even in the latest version v3.3.6 (non-sass) too.

Answer (score 5):

It would be nice if this were possible by tweaking a variable in the LESS, but I don't think it is.

From [variables.less](https://raw.github.com/twitter/bootstrap/master/less/variables.less):

```
// Typography
// -------------------------
@sansFontFamily:        "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
@serifFontFamily:       Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
@monoFontFamily:        Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;

@baseFontSize:          14px;
@baseFontFamily:        @sansFontFamily;
@baseLineHeight:        20px;
@altFontFamily:         @serifFontFamily;

@headingsFontFamily:    inherit; // empty to use BS default, @baseFontFamily
@headingsFontWeight:    bold;    // instead of browser default, bold
@headingsColor:         inherit; // empty to use BS default, @textColor
```

So you could scale *all* of the text by changing `@baseFontSize`, but unfortunately there's no separate `@baseHeaderFontSize`. You could always fork the project though!

**Edit 2:** As @merv points out, header sizes are to be based on `@baseFontSize` [from 2.1.2](http://gist.github.com/3773239).

**Original Edit:** It actually looks like the heading sizes are hardcoded anyway: [type.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/type.less):

```
h1 { font-size: 36px; line-height: 40px; }
h2 { font-size: 30px; line-height: 40px; }
h3 { font-size: 24px; line-height: 40px; }
h4 { font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px; }
h5 { font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; }
h6 { font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px; }
```

Comment: I guess the OP is using plain CSS. :)

Comment: Then he should switch to LESS. :)

Comment: In fact, even in plain CSS, if this were a variable OP could build a [custom bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables) with the variable set as they wished. It's not a variable though.

Comment: @RichardTowers Looks like in 2.1.2 they will be connecting the `@baseFontSize` to the h* tags.  See [tweet](https://twitter.com/twbootstrap/status/249996129771593728) and related [Gist](https://gist.github.com/3773239).

Comment: @merv Ah ha! Well then, as of 2.1.2 my original answer stands.

Answer (score 0):

Give a class to the `body` and give this CSS:

```
body.myClass h1,
body.myClass h2,
body.myClass h3,
body.myClass h4,
body.myClass h5,
body.myClass h6 {font-size: 0.9em;}
```

This gives you 90% of the original size. You can also give it as `90%`. :)

Comment: I believe, that is .9em or 90% of the body base font-size not the h1 font-size property declared elsewhere in the CSS.

Comment: @Mark, TBS declares `h1 {font-size: 36px;}`, and can't we override it as `.myClass h1 {font-size: 0.9em;}` which is 90% of the original? It works right?

Comment: My concern was that I think its not of the original, but of its inherited font-size. font-size of the body or parent element in the DOM that has an explicit font-size.

Comment: We use TBS in our application and this is how we override. :) It works in IE 7, IE 8, IE 9, FF, GC. That's why I suggested this method! :)

Comment: Using body.myClass h1, could be avoided as well if you just set the font-size for h1...h6, after the bootstrap @import. The specificity is the same.

Comment: Right! :) Good idea. But what the OP wants is 90% of the basefont. And another thing is, it is better idea to add our class and override the plugin's style. Better na? Portability.

Comment: The base font isn't 36px though, the base font in bootstrap is 16px. He wants ~30px font-size.

Comment: Now am really confused! :P Well, I meant the base-font not basefont size of `h1`. :)